# Diffrential pair circuit analysis in Pspice

Tags: transistors, circuit-analysis, bjt, pspice

I want to analyze this circuit in Pspice. But I do not know what values have to allocate to the resistors for the circuit to work properly (biasing).
[image]
[image]

Comment: It is one of the advantages of simulation programs that you can try different values without the danger to destroy the part. However, it is important to know how the simulation result should look like approximately.

Comment: There is no "it must be done like this", as a designer you will have to make **choices** regarding what (DC) voltages you want and what the biasing currents should be. You could start with biasing every transistor at Ic = 10 mA. Would 1 k resistors work for that?

Comment: As another recommendation: You should try to understand the circuit and - in particular - the task of each part! Therefore, are you familiar with the task of the 3 resistors R1, R2 and R3 ?

Comment: We may be able to help you. But we need to know what you expect from the circuit. We may have our own ideas but it's a long stretch to then assume that your expectations match any of ours. So be explicit and as precise as possible. Also, in order to target that help, we need to know what you know and what you do not know about this circuit. So talk about that aspect, as well. That would be the minimal effort on your part to let us see better where you are headed and why this circuit may (or may not) be appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve some "comparator" action, make R1 and R2 about 1 ohm.

And bias the PNP into linear region when the diffpair is balanced; try 0.6v/2mA = 300 ohms, for R7.

But this assumes you do want a COMPARATOR action.

You can explore some hysteresis, by inserting a 100,000 ohm resistor from output collector to any internal (internal to diffpair) positive_feedback point.